# Sorting in Pine Script

Tags: sorting, pine-script

Looks like this basic functionality is missing from v4 but is there a way to hack a solution?

I have several moving averages and would like to sort them by how far they are from the close value.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this. Not sure if the first for loop is needed but it's there in case the order of the cases affects the outcome.

```
get_diff(up, src, series1, series2, series3) =>
    diff = src * 999
    for c = 1 to 2
        for i = 1 to 3
            val = 0.0
            if i == 1
                val := series1
            if i == 2
                val := series2
            if i == 3
                val := series3
            diff := up and val > src and val - src < diff ? val - src : not up and val < src and src - val < diff ? src - val : diff
                
    if diff == src * 999
        diff := 0
    diff

support1 = close - get_diff(false, close, ma1, ma2, ma3)
support2 = support1 - get_diff(false, support1, ma1, ma2, ma3)
support3 = support2 - get_diff(false, support2, ma1, ma2, ma3)
resistance1 = close + get_diff(true, close, ma1, ma2, ma3)
resistance2 = resistance1 + get_diff(true, resistance1, ma1, ma2, ma3)
resistance3 = resistance2 + get_diff(true, resistance2, ma1, ma2, ma3)
```